# Replace string from column with NULL in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a df:

```
Col1   col2 
1222    abc
---    bbb
111  nmnm
```

Whenever I detect `---` in Col1 I want to convert that to NULL, how to do that?

Tried so far:

```
 select replace(Col1, '---', NULL) from df
```

But even after this the original table is unchanged

Comment: What you mean by "But even after this the original table is unchanged"? you wants to update the original table? that case you have to run a UPDATE script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the table:

```
UPDATE df
SET Col1 = NULL
WHERE Col1 = '---';
```

As for ad-hoc query:

```
select replace(Col1, '---', NULL) from df
<->
select nullif(col1, '---') AS col1 from df;
```